# Twisted SNI with deferreds

Tags: ssl, twisted, sni, pyopenssl

In our system, virtual hosts configuration is stored in redis. During connection setup, when the SNI is received, we would like to query redis for the correct certificate and key pair to use for the TLS connection and create a new `Context` instance with that attached.

The bulk of the code is similar to the accepted answer here: [Twisted listenSSL virtualhosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149119/twisted-listenssl-virtualhosts)

The issue we are facing is that, since accessing the certificates involves an additional network operation, we would like to make the `set_tlsext_servername_callback` function return a deferred.

Is there a way to tell Twisted/pyOpenSSL to wait until the deferred fires?

Edit: I found this link which seems promising, but falls short of providing a solution: https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-dev/2015-January/000480.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example of Twisted and SNI here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/txsni.  I would really, really like that callback to be able to take a Deferred.  I *think* that the way to do this would be to pause the underlying transport from delivering any further bytes either in or out ([`stopReading`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.4.0/api/twisted.internet.abstract.FileDescriptor.html#stopReading)/`stopWriting`) and then resume when the `Deferred` fires, after doing the rest of the SNI dance.  However, I'm not even sure if this is *possible* with OpenSSL, because the SNI is received with the rest of `ClientHello` and you may need to be able to react immediately to serve the correct certificate.  In this worst-possible-case scenario, you could feed the first chunk of bytes you receive into a dummy memory-BIO, wait for the TLS handshake, *throw it away* and never deliver any generated responses, and then don't initialize your "real" sub-transport until you've decided on which context object to use.

Hope this helps - and if you figure it out, please contribute a patch to TxSNI or Twisted!

Comment: Thanks @Glyph. I'm implementing the second approach you suggested (have been fighting to decode the ClientHello for a while). I already tried the first approach but was not able to pause the reading/writing successfully. I think because openssl's internal state machine gets into the wrong state when returning from the SNI callback.

Comment: Also interesting is https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_cert_cb.html and the ability to return -1 in OpenSSL > 1.0.2 to pause the handshake and resuming it later manually. No luck with that either though (I tried to hack into pyOpenSSL, but I think not everything is exposed yet).

Comment: Unfortunately older versions of OpenSSL see a *lot* of deployment, so we probably can't start depending on 1.0.2+ any time soon.  I think in order to implement that second option you probably need to write your own `WrapperProtocol` to control exactly when bytes get delivered, or write a patch to `twisted.protocols.tls` so that the bonus extra `Connection` object is built-in somehow…

Comment: In any case, if you get this figured out, please let us know about it, preferably on the mailing list, but also in an answer here!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/GaretJax/124c523a62ba48c9eec1 this works, but still has some rough edges. I'll clean it up in the next days.

Comment: I wonder if it wouldn't be easier to just manually parse the ClientHello (struct, yay). We would not have to mess with different connections/protocols/contexts...

Comment: @GaretJax - would you consider re-doing that gist as a patch to Twisted and opening a ticket for it?

Comment: No patch yet, but I opened a ticket and posted on the ML https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/8065

Comment: Everybody pay attention to @GaretJax being a model open source citizen :)